# How can I run Android applications on my computer?

Tags: applications, android-emulator

Is there any method for using Android applications on a computer, because I found [this](http://storychimes.com/apps-for-pc/download-wechat-for-windows-and-mac-free-of-charge) tutorial but my laptop just has 1 GB of RAM and works very hard. I want to use WeChat on my PC because I like it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need either Bluestacks or Youwave. I think Bluestacks can not be installed on your PC because of less RAM (minimum of 2gb recommended). So Youwave is your only option. It is easy to install and use.

- [Click here to download YouWave for Android on PC](http://youwave.com/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Bluestacks is the best so far, but I don't think it will run on a PC with 1GB of RAM.

As for YouWave, you need a few bucks to use it, so it's not a free tool. But there is another tool that might work well on your PC, it's called *Andy* and it's the best free alternative to Bluestacks so far.

Comment: here is a link to Andy http://www.andyroid.net/ good luck bro.

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to take a look at my [list of emulators](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/emulators) ­– the ones you will need are to be found at the end of the page. I personally use [android-x86](/questions/tagged/android-x86) in VirtualBox, which works fine – but you might have different demands. For just one app any of them might be a little "overkill" – and you might find it easier to install a [VNC-Server](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid#group_671) on your Android device to access the app via that. Which would have the advantage of doing even more on your device remotely ;)